# curlftpfs doesn't work for a username with a "@"

Tags: ftp, curl, curlftpfs

My hosting company makes all my usernames with a "@" in them.

```
curlftpfs user="user@domain.com:pass" ftp://ftp.domain.com/ ~/domain/
```

For some reason I get in response

> Error connecting to ftp: Couldn't
>   resolve host 'domain.com:pass'

I think that it's trying to connect to user@domain.com without the password 
(because of the @ sign)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cURL is interpreting everything after the first @ sign as the domain to connect to.  What you need to do is either fool cURL into working without the first @ sign, or find some other way of telling CurlFtpFS your username.

The former may possibly be done by replacing the @ with the URL encoded %40 - it may or may not work - try it and see.

The other way can be to see if there is a `--username` or `--user` parameter to CurlFtpFS that can be used instead of including it in the URL.  I am not familiar enough with CurlFtpFS to know if there is or not off hand.  The manual pages should tell you if there is or not.

Comment: holy crap, I did this command sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other ftp://user%40domain.com:pass@domain.com/ ~/domain/
And now for some reason I can't do an "ls" on my home directory!

Comment: @Asaf: When you run `ls`, it calls stat() on each item in the directory; when it reaches `~/domain`, it has to wait until curlftpfs responds. (For this problem, I usually put all remote mountpoints in a separate directory, such as `~/fs/` or `~/mnt/`.) Since curlftpfs is FUSE-based, you can kill its process if it hangs for too long.

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering if you are missing the `-o` switch, so that your example above of:

```
curlftpfs user="user@domain.com:pass" ftp://ftp.domain.com/ ~/domain/
```

should be:

```
curlftpfs -o user="user@domain.com:pass" ftp://ftp.domain.com/ ~/domain/
```

Does that work?